# Deserialize multiple record of JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have following JSON

```
string json = @"[[{""campaignId"":201410018,""programCode"":""54321""},{""reason"":201410018,"‌​"about"":""54321""}],[{""campaignId"":201410019,""programCode"":""54322""},{""rea‌​son"":201410018,""about"":""54321""}]]"
```

And i have created following class

```
public class JSONResponse
    {

        public number[] number{ get; set; }
        public Inf[] inf{ get; set; }
    }

    public class number
    {

        public int reason { get; set; }
        public string about { get; set; }

    }
    public class Inf
    {

        public int campaignId { get; set; }
        public string programCode { get; set; }
    }
```

to deserialize i am calling below code

```
List<List<JSONResponse>> myDeserializedObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<JSONResponse>>>(jsonstr);
```

But still both of my class data is null.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON has 2 different object types in the same array, you can't do typical and the easy way to deserialize into objects. Unless you have control over the JSON to change the structure into something that doesn't have the Inf and number object within same array, your only option is why Expando/dynamic objects. The code below parses the provided JSON into your existing class structure.

```
static List<JSONResponse> Parse(string json)
{
    var responses = new List<JSONResponse>();
    //string)obj[0][0].programCode.Value;
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
    {
        //responses[i] = new JSONResponse() {
        var inf = new List<Inf>();
        var numbers = new List<number>();
        for (int j = 0; j < obj[i].Count; j++)
        {
            if (obj[i][j].campaignId != null)
                inf.Add(new Inf()
                    {
                        campaignId = (int) obj[i][j].campaignId.Value,
                        programCode = obj[i][j].programCode.Value
                    });
            if (obj[i][j].reason != null)
                numbers.Add(new number()
                    {
                        about = obj[i][j].about.Value,
                        reason = (int)obj[i][j].reason.Value
                    });
        }
        responses.Add(new JSONResponse()
            {
                number = numbers.ToArray(),
                inf = inf.ToArray()
            });

    }
    return responses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't have the structure you show in your classes.  Rather than a list of lists of responses containing arrays of `Inf` and `number` classes, you json has a list of pairs of `Inf` and `number` classes.  You can see this if you paste your json into http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  It would make sense to package each pair into a container class, but unfortunately the pairs are transmitted in an array rather than as distinct properties, so they don't have names that could be mapped to class property names.  Instead, you can write a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to parse the array and assign the fields appropriately:

```
public class number
{
    public int reason { get; set; }
    public string about { get; set; }
}

public class Inf
{
    public int campaignId { get; set; }
    public string programCode { get; set; }
}

public class JSONResponse
{
    public number number { get; set; }
    public Inf Inf { get; set; }

    public static List<JSONResponse> DeserializeList(string jsonstr)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONResponse>>(jsonstr, new JSONResponseConverter());
    }
}

class JSONResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(JSONResponse).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JSONResponse response = new JSONResponse();
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        if (array.Count != 2)
        {
            // Or maybe throw an exception?
            Debug.WriteLine("Unexpected array length for " + array.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var entry in array)
        {
            if (entry["campaignId"] != null)
            {
                response.Inf = entry.ToObject<Inf>();
            }
            else if (entry["reason"] != null)
            {
                response.number = entry.ToObject<number>();
            }
            else
            {
                // Or maybe throw an exception?
                Debug.WriteLine("Unknown entry " + entry.ToString());
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
        object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in charge of your data then rather than make things complex you could change your structure

eg instead of

```
@"[[{""campaignId"":201410018,""programCode"":""54321""},{""reason"":201410018,"‌​"about"":""54321""}],[{""campaignId"":201410019,""programCode"":""54322""},{""rea‌​son"":201410018,""about"":""54321""}]]"
```

try

```
@"[{info:{""campaignId"":201410018,""programCode"":""54321""},number:{""reason"":201410018,"‌​"about"":""54321""}},{info:{""campaignId"":201410019,""programCode"":""54322""},number:{""rea‌​son"":201410018,""about"":""54321""}}]"
```

and to handle that

```
public class JSONResponse
{
    public number number{ get; set; }
    public Inf info{ get; set; }
}

public class number
{

    public int reason { get; set; }
    public string about { get; set; }

}
public class Inf
{

    public int campaignId { get; set; }
    public string programCode { get; set; }
}
```

now you only have a list of JSONResponse to deal with